# Calling vuex getters function in context depending on parameter

Tags: vuex

I am currently setting up my vue.js project with vuex. I have a structure like:

`state.Task.tasklist.getters.getAll`

`state.Project.projectlist.getters.getAll`

Now I have a generic component that should list all elements depending on a prop or param (e.g. myModel = Task)

I would like to have a computed field: `genericGetAll(e.g. myModel)` that returns:

`state.Task.tasklist.getters.getAll`

in case myModel is Task, but I would like to have this really generic. E.g.

`state.{myModel}.{myModel}list.getter.getAll`

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: In vuex you can address a getter using an array like syntax, something like `store.getters[\`${someModule}/getAll\`]`. [namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the quick reply. I am afraid there is some room of improvement for making myself familiar with the vuex documentation.